# Creating polygons from binary image using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, raster-conversion

Here I got a binary image of buildings (black and white image) and I need to convert them to building polygons:
[image]

The expected outcome will be a vector file with building polygons based on the image like this: blue as polygon edge and red as polygon area

[image]

However, I tried `Raster -> Conversion -> Polygonize and Extraction -> Contour`. The polygon created is not what I need:

[image]

Are there anyways to achieve the expected outcome?

Comment: If you zoom in on one of the building polygons, is the building boundary made up of lots of tiny squares? Because that problem can be solved by reclassifying your raster. In your case, convert all the gray cells to one single value, and convert all the white cells to a different value.

Comment: Hi @csk, I guess you are talking about r.reclass? Actually my original image is in black and white (I set alpha value for comparing the coordinates with other maps), does that still need a reclassifying process?

Comment: Look at the raster histogram (in the layer properties) to find out if you need to reclassify your raster. You should only have two different values. All the "white" cells should be one value, and all the "black" cells should be a different single value. Eg, if you have a three-band raster in the range 0-255, all the cells should have the value 0 or 255. If the cells have values like (0, 1, 2, 253, 254, 255) then you need to reclassify the raster so they all have 0 or 255.